# Efficient batch derivative operations in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using Pytorch to implement a neural network that has (say) 5 inputs and 2 outputs

```
class myNetwork(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self):
      super(myNetwork,self).__init__()
      self.layer1 = nn.Linear(5,32)
      self.layer2 = nn.Linear(32,2)
   def forward(self,x):
      x = torch.relu(self.layer1(x))
      x = self.layer2(x)
      return x
```

Obviously, I can feed this an (N x 5) Tensor and get an (N x 2) result,

```
net = myNetwork()
nbatch = 100
inp = torch.rand([nbatch,5])
inp.requires_grad = True
out = net(inp)
```

I would now like to compute the derivatives of the NN output with respect to one element of the input vector (let's say the 5th element), for each example in the batch. I know I can calculate the derivatives of one element of the output with respect to all inputs using `torch.autograd.grad`, and I could use this as follows:

```
deriv = torch.zeros([nbatch,2])
for i in range(nbatch):
   for j in range(2):
      deriv[i,j] = torch.autograd.grad(out[i,j],inp,retain_graph=True)[0][i,4]
```

However, this seems very inefficient: it calculates the gradient of `out[i,j]` with respect to every single element in the batch, and then discards all except one. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

By virtue of backpropagation, if you did only compute the gradient w.r.t a single input, the computational savings wouldn't necessarily amount to much, you would only save some in the first layer, all layers afterwards need to be backpropagated either way.

So this may not be the optimal way, but it doesn't actually create much overhead, especially if your network has many layers.

By the way, is there a reason that you need to loop over `nbatch`? If you wanted the gradient of each element of a batch w.r.t a parameter, I could understand that, because pytorch will lump them together, but you seem to be solely interested in the input...

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but `torch.autograd.grad()` expects the 'output' parameter to be a scalar, so I don't see how I can avoid the loop over `nbatch`?

Comment: As per https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.grad , it should actually allow you to pass along entire tensors, shouldn't it? I can understand that you need to loop over both outputs because torch will sum their gradients, but looping over the batch shouldn't be necessary (but I could be wrong!)